# How do i access the entry variables in my gui class in another function?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I created a basic GUI and want to take inputs from the user. I used tkinter for most of the code. Here is the code-

```
class myGUI:
    global InA0, Inb, InC, Ina, InL

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("Flow through nozzles")

        self.label = Label(master, text ="Consider the incompressible flow of a fluid through a nozzle. The area of the nozzle is given by A = A0(1−bx) and the inlet velocity varies according to U=C(1+at), where")
        self.label.grid(rowspan=1)

        self.labA = Label(master, text ="A0")
        self.labA.grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.InA0 = Entry(master)
        self.InA0.grid(row=2,column=2)
        ....
        there is code for 4 more variables with the same code as the above 4 lines
        ....     
        
        self.inputbutton = Button(master, text="Submit", command=self.inputs())
        self.inputbutton.grid(row=5, column=1)

        self.close_button = Button(master, text="Close", command=master.quit)
        self.close_button.grid(row=5, column=2)

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

    def inputs(self):
        global A0, L, b, a, C
        A0 = InA0.get()
        b = Inb.get()
        C = InC.get()
        a = Ina.get()
        L = InL.get()
        print(A0, b, C, a, L)
```

I wanna access the entry variables from the class so that i can take input values from the user.

When i run the code it says that the name "InA0" is not defined. I am quite a noob at programming and this my first time writing code for a gui. I have tried to access the variables in the class through different ways but i just dont know how to access the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close. Only thing you are missing is that when you name a variable with `self` then that is now part of it's name. You can't leave it off sometimes. So try:

```
A0 = self.InA0.get()
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Now i face another problem, where when i type in the values and press the submit button, it doesnt seem to take the inputs as there is no output in the console for the print( A0, b, C, a, L)

Comment: `command=self.inputs()` should be `command=self.inputs`.